# What does "trade studies" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Middle School
>
> High School
>
> **Trade Studies**
>
> College  Graduate
>
> Post Graduate

In terms of level of education, what does "trade studies" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trade Studies would be the pursuit of a vocational education at a [Vocational School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocational_school) The word 'trade' refers to a skilled manual labor job and vocational schools are schools that train students to do those jobs. Some examples of trades are plumbing, electric, auto and diesel mechanics, carpentry, etc. A trade school might also teach some business skills such as accounting, so that a graduate would be able to run a business.

Your question shows Trade Studies placed appropriately within the hierarchy of education levels. A student at a Trade School, or Vocational School, would probably be expected to have finished high school, but not to have gone to college. A trade school would train a student to go directly into the job market without going to college, so it is often the highest level of education that people reach before starting to work.